# Passing parameter between XAML pages

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I have following requirement, I have 4 pages. First 3 pages prompt user to enter some information and finally on fourth page I do some processing and display the result.

I came up with this approach. I have created a class with all the field user enter in various pages

```
ref class CameraWiFiInfo sealed
{

   public:
   property String^ sCameraName;
   property String^ sWiFIName;
   property String^ sWifiPassword;
   CameraWiFiInfo()
   {
    sCameraName = ref new String;
    sWiFIName = ref new String;
    sWifiPassword = ref new String;
   }
};
```

I am trying to pass this object as follows

```
  PAGE #1
    CameraWiFiInfo^ cameraInfo = ref new CameraWiFiInfo();
    cameraInfo->sCameraName = txtCameraName->Text;
    this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(WifiCheck::typeid),cameraInfo);

  PAGE#2
  void Page2::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs^ e)
  {
       (void) e;    // Unused parameter
       CameraWiFiInfo^ cameraInfo= e->Parameter ;


  }
```

I am getting error here error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'Platform::Object ^' to 'CameraWiFiInfo ^'.

I goggled in the net I didn't get any suitable C++/Win Rt XAML example to pass the data from one XAML page to another.If any one tried data passing in C++/Win Rt  Please suggest on this.

Comment: I think you just need a cast: `CameraWiFiInfo^ cameraInfo= (CameraWiFiInfo^)e->Parameter;`

Comment: @svick I tried that it is not working.

Comment: *How* is it not working? What *does* it do? What error are you getting?

Comment: Also, have you read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394)?

Comment: I am sorry It is working now it is due to some other error..Thanks @svick can you move this to answer I will mark it..thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an explicit cast:

```
CameraWiFiInfo^ cameraInfo= (CameraWiFiInfo^)e->Parameter;
```

But be careful when doing this, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394):

> To enable serialization of the frame's state using `GetNavigationState`, you must pass only basic types to this method, such as string, char, numeric, and GUID types. […] In general, we discourage passing a non-basic type as a parameter to `Navigate` because it can’t be serialized when the application is suspended, and can consume more memory […]